# Does encryption for app.config is secure?

Tags: c#

I already get through all the way process on how to secure any username/password or private information that need to be encrypted. And as I figure it out, I found that there are many people suggest to encrypt the app.config for security purpose. But if i encrypt it, does it really secure? Since i want to use it for the FTP purpose. In case, want to know my coding i provide it.

```
 sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("remoteFtpPath").ToString(),
            PortNumber = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port")),
            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("userName"),
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password"),
            TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TlsHostCertificateFingerprint").ToString(),
            FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,
        };
```

Basically the current app config is not encrypted yet

Comment: The purpose of encrypting app.config is to secure the sensitive configuration data. In case the file goes in to wrong hands or server gets compromised the data stored in the app.config such as usernames, passwords, connectionstrings, keys, token etc should not be revealed just like that. May not be 100% solid but this surely makes it hard for the hacker to crack the file and get the details.

Comment: I see, because before this I saw most tutorial use  aspnet_regiis tool to encrypt and decrypt a file. If I put the plain text inside the .CS file which example is  string password="FTPpassword", it does not secure since people can easily decompile the file itself. So i found out that people encrypt the String itself. Base on your view which encryption is better? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: There are standard ways available for encrypting app.config. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encrypting-app-config-for-multiple-machines/

Comment: thank you very much @ChetanRanpariya now i able to encrypt and decrypt inside my machine as well

Comment: the problem currently that i face is to decrypt in other machine as i need to deploy the console application inside the client machine which need to decrypt the app.config as well. Is there any suggestion for this since i get through everything and it state about web farm? @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about encryption , yes the encryption is secure and standard. The file cannot be decrypted anywhere else except for the machine and except for the user account which had encrypted the config file .

Now if the administrator is compromised i.e. from and insider threat aspect , of course this is not secure.

Comment: Since i able to encrypt the part that i want inside my machine,  Like you said that it cant be decrypt  in other machine. And as my objective is to put the console application into client machine which got problem to do the decryption process. And as i go through i found out there is a process that provide the RSA key to the client machine for decryption, so basically when i share the key. it will cause the problem right? but the only things i found is for web config process under aspnet_iis regis tool which for web purpose, how am i able to decrypt it for the console application for my client